# How to use INNER JOIN and FOREIGN KEY between two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I got two tables in my databse and I am displaying them in two different php pages.

How can I display the contents of the first table from the page where I am displaying the second table, row by row.

What I want to achive is: each row of the second table have a button that onclick will show (throw a modal-pop-up) the info which are in the first table.

So the button of the row1-table2 will show me only the info of row1-table1 and so on....

I am able to implement the button for each row and the pop-up but I can Only display the info of the entire first table and not of the single row associated.

[image]
-------------code update

```
    <div class="container">
          <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm- hero-feature">
              <div class="thumbnail">  
          <?php
    include("../includes/connection.php");
    if ($link->connect_errno > 0) {
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $link->connect_error . ']');
    }
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
$results = $link>query("UPDATE job SET status='$_POST[status]', priority='$_POST[priority]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'");
$results = $link>query("UPDATE **table2** SET status='$_POST[status]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'");}

    $sql = "SELECT * from job";
    if (!$result = $link->query($sql)) {
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $link->error . ']');
    }
    echo "…………./* Get field information for all columns */………… "

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<form action='' method=post>";

    echo "<tr class='info'>
    <input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $row['id'] . ">
    <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td> 
    <td>" . $row['device'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['model'] . "</td> 
    <td>" . $row['problem'] . "</td>

    <td><select class='form-control col-sm-10' id='status' name='status'>
    <option value=" . $row['status'] . " >" . $row['status'] . "</option>
                      <option value='new'>New</option>
                      <option value='progress'>Progress</option>
                      <option  value='wait'>Wait</option>
                      <option value='done'>Done</option>
                      <option value='close'>Close</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><select class='form-control col-sm-10' id='priority' name='priority'>
    <option value=" . $row['priority'] . " >" . $row['priority'] . "</option>
                            <option value='high'>High</option>
                            <option value='medium'>Medium</option>
                            <option  value='low'>Low</option>
    </select></td>

    <td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['priority'] . "</td>

    **<td>   <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' name='update'>Update</button></td>**

    **<td> <a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' datatarget='#myModal'>Info</a></td>**
    </tr>";    echo "</form>";}echo "  </tbody>

    </table>";

    ?>
    <div class="container">
      !-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Customer Information</h4>

    </div> <div class="modal-body">
    <?php
    include("../includes/connection.php");

    if ($link->connect_errno > 0) {
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $link->connect_error . ']');
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * from **table2**";
    if (!$result = $link->query($sql)) {
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $link->error . ']');
    }
    echo "
    <table class='table'>
        <thead><tr>";
    /* Get field information for all columns */
    while ($finfo = $result->fetch_field()) {
    echo "<th>" . $finfo->name . "</th>";}echo "
    </tr></thead><tbody>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr class='info'>
        <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td> 
                    <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['mail'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['number'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['paymenttype'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['faktura'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
        </tr>";}echo "
        </tbody>
        </table>";

    ?> </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
```

Comment: 2 questions. 1) the code for table2 looks like what you have been referring as table1 because it has that faktura field, can you post up the code for the other table, particular how you do the buttons? 2) the code you have already posted, is that a separate file to the code for the first table or are they in the same file?

Comment: I updated my code.  In the same page I have the php code that gather table2 and a div (modal-popup), with a php code that gather table1 onclick of the button "Info" of table2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i am understanding you want a one-to-one/many relationship between the tables (depending if you are planning to reuse customer data).

in table2 have a new field which will contain IDs from table1, this is your [foreign key](http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-foreign-keys-quicker-database-development/).

> ## What are Foreign Keys?
>
> A foreign key establishes a relationship, or constraint, between two tables.

now i am unsure exactly how you are bring up data when you click "info" but if you are running a separate query when it is clicked then you just pass the table1 ID that's stored in table2 in a WHERE clause like this

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE custId = ?
```

where `?` is however you generate your queries in PHP (using paramatized queries or generating a a string with PHP variables).

if you need the data from table1 loaded at the same time as table2 then you would use an INNER JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM table2 AS t2
    INNER JOIN table1 AS t1
        ON t2.custID = t1.custID
```

this way for every row in table2 it will have a row from table1. this will only work if table1's ID are **unique** otherwise you can get

NOTE: good practice is not to use `SELECT *`, it's good when debugging but in proper code you want every field named especially when you do joins incase if 2 tables have field which are named the same

Comment: To be more precise:I have a pageinsert.php that populate at the same time table1 and table2. And.... I have a page.php which show the table2. The table2 has a column with the button INFO which open a modal popup. In the modal pop-up i wrote a query that shows the table1. So now for all of the info buttons i get the entire table1 diplayed. But what i want is to connect each row of the table1 with row of the tabe2. In exemple: the button info of row[2] of table2 will show me only the row[2] of table1 and so on.....

Comment: @gigi you would still have a field (foreign key) in table2 to store the id of the matching row in table1 as [there is no consistent default row order](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6053/28187). if you look at this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63442/4) you'll how you filter the results of table1 with whatever the selected you have.

Comment: Thank you. I am reading around about it. I use phpmyadmin.... I went into table2 and created a new column and assigned a UNIQUE properties to it. Then I went into STRUCTURE and RELATION VIEW, there are two choiche....Foreign key constraints and internal relation.....what to choose? Am I in the wrong place ? thanks for the tip....I am on it...

Comment: @gigi if you have created the field for the table that should me more than enough. setting up an 'official' relationship between the 2 tables really only helps out when your doing an `INNER JOIN` and need to improve performance

Comment: Could you tell me what are t1 and t2 in the exemple you made in sqlfiddle?Is it just to not rewrite table1 and table2?

Comment: In exemple: if I write $sql = "SELECT * from customer  WHERE id=1" (clicking on the info button of the table2) I get all the info of the first row of table1. And thats ok. But the button of the second row should show me "SELECT * from customer  WHERE id=2". I guess is stupid to write a single query for each row. I dont get how I can create the mechanism in order to do just one query.

Comment: @gigi `t1` and `t2` are table alias. when you do `SELECT * FROM table` you can use `AS alias`. this is generally used when you join multiple table for when 2 tables have a field by the same name. in your example if i was to join the 2 tables and i wanted to show both `status` fields i would have to use `table1.status, table2,status`. using `AS` i can shorten the names down to what i specified. it's a good habit to get into that whenever you do `FROM table` or `INNER JOIN table` to always have `AS` and what you want to name them, even if you just copy and paste the original table name in

Comment: @gigi without seeing the code you use to generate the tables i can't give you exact code but i would assume you are using a loop to show table2. in  that loop you would have something like (using your code) `$sql = "SELECT * from customer WHERE id=".$row["table1_id"]`. ofcause this is assuming the loops you are using is something like `foreach($sqlresault as $row)` where `$sqlresault` is the variable that's used to store the data from table2

Comment: To generate table2 in the modal-pop up after clicking the button, i just use the simple $sql = "SELECT * from table1"; because what i need to show(clicking the button info) is all the info of the row of table2. Code updated in my question. Thanks for all the hints.